# How does Rainlendar achieve transparency with wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

[Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php) is a fantastic cross platform calendar program that is written with wxWidgets. How does it achieve the transparency effect? Does anyone have any example code which demonstrates the transparency effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that they could be using a `wxScreenDC` to draw directly to the screen (while preserving the background contents). Unlike receiving paint events or erase events, you create a `wxScreenDC` on the stack at your choosing, which means that you need to refresh yourself (most likely via a timer of some sort). If you don't, background applications will eventually repaint themselves over your `wxScreenDC` contents.

[Here's the API listing](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_screen_d_c.html)

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, usage (besides the need to call StartDrawingOnTop and EndDrawingOnTop) is identical to any other `wxDC`.

Answer (score 1):

[wxTopLevelWindow::SetTransparent()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#8e37aff45a001a83ff49745298a6978e) method may be what you need.

Comment: SetTransparent makes the whole window transparent. The idea with this calendar (it appears) is that it draws fully opaque images onto transparent backgrounds (SetTransparent would make everything equally transparent).